# Android data binding not working

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to do a simple test example with `Android Data Binding`. I only want to show in my fragment the text `"test"` in the `EditText` named `"title"`, but this text is  not shown. Here is my code:

**TestVM.java**

```
public class TestVM extends BaseObservable {

    public TestVM() {}

    @Bindable
    public String getText() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**fr_login.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>
    <variable
        name="test"
        type="de.theappguys.templateandroid.viewmodel.TestVM"/>
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@{test.text}"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**FrLogin.java**

```
@EFragment
public class FrLogin extends Fragment {

...

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fr_login, container, false);

    return binding.getRoot();
}

...
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {

.....

   dataBinding {
       enabled = true
   }

....
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to set value to your binding

```
FrLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fr_login, container, false);
binding.setTest(new TestVM());
```

Problem with your code is that there is no connection between your model and `Fragment`.

Comment: Despite knowing this I wasted an hour, thank you for saving my night :)

Answer (score 9):

you have to bind your `ViewModel`  as well. E.g

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fr_login, container, false);
    binding.setTest(new TestVM());
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Comment: Cool! really nice, it is working like a charm, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add this line in `build.gradle` (:app):

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     private Context mContent;

     @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FragmentBrandBinding binding = FragmentBrandBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        mContent = view.getContext();
        return view;
      }
```